# Removing eventemitter to avoid code to run twice

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm developing an Angular 2 application with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and the Visual Studio 2017 Angular's Web application template.

I don't know why an event is trigger twice.

This is the `law.component.html`:

```
<p *ngIf="!laws"><em>Loading...</em></p>
Legislaciones:&nbsp;
<select #l (change)="lawChanges(l.value)">
    <option></option>
    <option *ngFor="let law of laws" [ngValue]="law">{{law.name}}</option>
</select>
```

This is the `law.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, Inject, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'law',
    templateUrl: './law.component.html'
})

export class LawComponent {
    public laws: Law[];

    @Output()
    change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

    constructor(private http: Http,
        @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string) {

        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/Law').subscribe(result => {
            this.laws = result.json() as Law[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }

    lawChanges(selectedLaw: Law) {
        console.log("selected law: " + selectedLaw.value + " " + selectedLaw.name + ".");
        this.change.emit(selectedLaw.value);
    }
}

interface Law {
    value: number;
    name: string;
}
```

Where I have added included the `law.component.html` into the `product.component.html`:

```
<law (change)="lawChanged($event)"></law>
```

This the `product.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, Inject, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'product',
    templateUrl: './product.component.html'
})
export class ProductComponent {
    public products: Product[];
    private law: number;

    constructor(private http: Http,
        @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string,
        private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    lawChanged(law: number) {
        console.log("lawchange: " + law);

        this.law = law;
        this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'api/Product/'+ law).subscribe(result => {
            this.products = result.json() as Product[];
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
}

interface Product {
    productCode: string;
    description: string;
    law: number;
    name: string;
    comment: string;
}
```

This is the angular's version (`ng --version`):

```
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / ? \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.4.4
node: 6.11.3
os: win32 x64
```

I get this in the console:

```
selected law: 1  law.component.ts:25:2
lawchange: 1  product.component.ts:21:2
lawchange: [object Event]  product.component.ts:21:2
```

And this on the node output (I think is node. It is a console running the server):

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50356/api/Product/1
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50356/api/Product/%5Bobject%20Event%5D
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**
If I change the `law.component.html` code to this one (removing the `#l (change)="lawChanges(l.value)"` and also the `[ngValue]="law"`):

```
<select>
    <option></option>
    <option *ngFor="let law of laws" [value]="law.value">{{law.name}}</option>
</select>
```

And how I have integrated the `law component` into the `product component`:

```
<law (change)="lawChanged($event.target.value)"></law>
```

And now it runs perfectly. I don't know if this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Did you try to `enableProdMode` ? Can you make a plunkr to reproduce the issue ?

Comment: Try $event:
`<select (change)="lawChanges($event)">
    <option></option>
    <option *ngFor="let law of laws" [ngValue]="law">{{law.name}}</option>
</select>`

Comment: @Swoox I have tried and I get the same.

Comment: Then try to add `$event.stopPropagation()` in your event handler in the law.component

Comment: Can you please check (change)="lawChanges(l.value)" and change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>()

Comment: I have updated the question with the solution I have found it. But I don't know why I have to remove eventemitter to make it works.